# Dowload File Primerfaces Java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Estoy implementando un código para descargar con `primerfaces` un **pdf** y me tira el siguiente error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:89)
>       at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mi código es el Siguiente

**El bean del java.class:**

```
public StreamedContent getFileDownload() {

    InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream
            (ParamSistema.getParametro("rutaPdf") + this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
    System.out.println(ParamSistema.getParametro("rutaPdf") + this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
    fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf",   this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
    return fileDownload;
}
public void setFileDownload(StreamedContent fileDownload) {
    this.fileDownload = fileDownload;
}
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<p:commandButton id="btnPdf" icon="ui-icon-document"
                            onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
                            title="Bajar Documento">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{comodatoBean.fileDownload}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
```

> PD: "rutaPdf" es igual a esto : ***C:/certificado/***

Por lo que yo entiendo a pesar de que le entrego un valor al `InputStream` siempre queda como nulo y no entiendo porque , lo intente de la manera en la que esta en el código y con  **getClass()**. cualquier ayuda es bien recibida de ante mano gracias.

---

Lo probe de la Siguiente Manera:

```
    InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(ParamSistema.getParametro("rutaPdf") + this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
    fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf",   this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
```

y el resultado fue el mismo.

Y esto muestra en el log:

```
Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Informatica'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falto fue inicializar la variable de InputStream  que seria la primera linea la otra es solo para que sepa qu es pdf

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("certificado.pdf");
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/pdf", "certificado.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el problema con el Siguiente Codigo:

```
public void prepDownload() throws Exception {
      File file = new File(ParamSistema.getParametro("rutaPdf") + this.comodato.getNumComodato() + ".pdf");
      InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
      setFileDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
}
```

El problema era que no podía salir a descargar el archivo fuera de mi workspace y lo solucione con ese código. Para los que comentaron gracias.